# New tag proposal: "FTPS" tag for "FTP over SSL" related issues

Tags: discussion, tags

System suggested to discuss it on meta, as "ftp" tag exist.

Should we use "ftp" and "ssl" tags in case of questions relating to "FTPS" or shall be new tag created?

Comment: Please mark terdon's answer as accepted so others know this issue's been resolved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That seems very reasonable. We already have [ftp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ftp) and [sftp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sftp) and ftps is distinct from both of them.

I've gone ahead and created the [ftps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ftps) tag.

Comment: Thanks! I've created short description proposal (waiting for peer review), making it bold that "ftps" should not be confused with "sftp".

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki thanks, but please don't describe the tag itself in the tag excerpt. Excerpts should explain how the tag should be used on the site rather than the tag's subject. Please have a look at the [tag excerpt guidelines](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts). I changed your suggestion accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! After reading guideline I've learned more about proper excerpts, so I will know for future! :)